# Android: ViewPager displays only first fragment, other pages blank

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that displays a series of FoodItem as Fragments. That part works just fine.

Now, I want to have a function such that if a user clicks on a button, they can view more information about that FoodItem.

For that, I want to replace the clicked Fragment with another Fragment. I modified this code [here](https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example) to suit my purpose. It works -- when I click the button, it replaces that certain Fragment. But it only displays and works for one Fragment. Other fragments are blank entirely.

Here's my adapter and fragments:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<FoodItem> items;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<FoodItem> items) {
    super(fm);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    System.out.println("PRINT: POS " + position);
    RootFragment f = new RootFragment();
    return f.newInstance(position);


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}


public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{

    private final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        System.out.println("PRINT: INSTANCE" + sectionNumber);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_layout, container, false);
        singleItem = items.get(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));

        // populate views here

        //Below is the button for replacing the Fragment with another Fragment.

        Button testMore = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.testMore);
        testMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                                trans.replace(R.id.root_frame, new MoreInfoFragment().newInstance(getArguments().
                        getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                trans.addToBackStack(null);

                trans.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}

public class MoreInfoFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public MoreInfoFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        MoreInfoFragment fragment = new MoreInfoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MoreInfoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more_info_layout, container, false);
        singleItem = items.get(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));

        //populate views here

        return view;

    }
}

public class RootFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "RootFragment";
    private final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public RootFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        RootFragment fragment = new RootFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_fragment, container, false);

       FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

      transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, new PlaceholderFragment().newInstance(getArguments().
        getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        System.out.println("PRINT: ROOT" + getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));


        transaction.commit();

        return view;
    }

}
}
```

Here's my Main Activity:

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private static ArrayList<FoodItem> sample;
private PagerContainer mContainer;


public CardLayout(){

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_layout);

   //Sample array
    sample = new ArrayList<>();
    sample.add(new FoodItem("French Fries", "Super delicious and crispy!"))
    sample.add(new FoodItem("Burger", "Made with real Krabby Patty"))
    sample.add(new FoodItem("Pickles", "So green")) // This is the only one that displays

   //PagerContainer is a FrameLayout that has a ViewPager as a child. 
   //I want my ViewPager to display edges of the previous and next part so    
   //PagerContainer is used for that purpose.
    mContainer = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

   // This is to adjust the viewpager according to size of screen 
    mContainer.getViewTreeObserver().
            addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    height = mContainer.getHeight();

                    double heightSize =  height * 0.8;
                    height = (int) heightSize;
                    double widthSize = height*0.6;
                    width = (int) widthSize;


                    mViewPager.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, Gravity.CENTER));
                    mViewPager.setPageMargin(width /30);


                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        mContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    else
                        mContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), sample);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount());


    mViewPager.setClipChildren(false);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Oh, the Fragment that's displaying is not even the first one in my ArrayList! It's the last.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I've looked through this code about 10 times and I still couldn't find what could have prevented the other pages from displaying.

For example, this is how the first page looks like:
[image]

If I slide to the second page, it's totally white (my background color for root_fragment)

[image]

And that goes for every fragments after.

Do you guys have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: ViewPager cannot be used for this. Either handle the layout change within the item fragment or overlay the detail fragment over the view pager.

Comment: What do you mean overlay the detail fragment? Do I create a new activity over the viewPager?

Comment: I realize now it's unnecessarily complicated, the first suggestion is way easier. Just have a FrameLayout (it's the fragment's view) which contains the default view and the detail view. Then just change their visibility to GONE and the other VISIBLE and vice versa and you're done for now.

Comment: Oh, tried it and it works! It's a much simpler solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Override the method getItem() in your SelectionsPageAdapter

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        if (position == 0) 
        {
            Fragment tab1 = new PlaceholderFragment ();
            return tab1;

        } else if (position == 1)           
        {
            Fragment tab2 = new MoreInfoFragment ();
            return tab2;

        } else if (position == 2) {

            Fragment tab3 = new RootFragment ();
            return tab3;

        } 

    }
```

Comment: GetItem is called only once for each position, when the fragment on that position is created.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't really what I was looking for. At first, all fragments in ViewPager are of the PlaceholderFragment instance. Then, when I click a button in one of Fragment, then it is replace by a MoreInfoFragment. And, in truth, I'll be using an arraylist so I can't use an if-else in the position of getItem